# AVERAGEIF function on wildcard selected spreadsheet name

Tags: excel, average, formula

Hoping I could get some assistance on an `AVERAGEIF` type of function please.

My workbook has the following worksheets: A, A Summary, B, B Summary, C, C Summary, etc.

I'm looking to average the range `K16:T16` for all Summary worksheets.

The criteria is for the average to ignore "zero" values.

Would there be a formula that would assist in this?

In a simplified world, the formula I'd be looking at would be something like `=AVERAGEIF('* Summary'!K16:T16,">0")`...?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Row2 ColumnA enter:

```
="'"&CHAR(ROW()+63)&" Summary'!K16:T16"
```

In Row2 ColumnB enter:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A2),">0")
```

In Row 2 ColumnC enter:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(A2),">0")
```

Copy the above three formulae down to suit (but not so far as to see `#REF!`).

In B1 enter:

```
=SUM(B2:B100000)
```

and copy across to C1.

In A1 (the result, hopefully!) enter:

```
=B1/C1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and I really like your idea. Unfortunately I was only using the ABC as examples... I'm sorry for the troubles! The spreadsheet I'm working on is meant to summarize the national workforce capability and workload planning. I need to average the data into 1 cell only. I've ended up consolidating the data from different sites into a helper worksheet to allow me to use the `AVERAGEIF` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use indirect to do this:

```
Colmumn 1   column2
```

```
A          =AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & " Summary'!K16:T16"),">0")
```

```
B          =AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("'" & A3 & " Summary'!K16:T16"),">0")
```

```
C          =AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("'" & A4 & " Summary'!K16:T16"),">0")
```

Fill column 1 with the letters eg a,b,c etc, then fill down the following into column 2

```
=AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT( "'" & A2 & " Summary'!K16:T16"),">0")
```

Indirect works by translating the quoted text for you the & are joiners.

so  "'" & A2 & " summary'!K16:T16" 
becomes 
'A Summary'!K16:T16" if a3 = A

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance. I'm actually looking to have the total average calculated into the 1 single cell though. I ended up creating a helper worksheet to consolidate all data on the different worksheets before calculating it onto the final summary worksheet.